# How to chunk in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Is there a nice way to chunk in Kotlin? I need a list into chunks of consecutive elements whose sum is less than X.

Example [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10  15 13 17 10] -> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7], [8], [9], [10]] (each chunk has sum less than 16)

I thought maybe chunked method would work but I can chunk only by size. For now, I just made the for loop in an imperative way.

Comment: What's a "nice" way? How is a for loop/imperative way not "nice"?

Comment: Can you please confirm that all elements after sequence is broken in input, should be discarded? In other words, that `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7], [8], [9], [10]]` is the actual expected result. I challenged the output in answer from gidds, but @ocos suggests that the spec may be wrong. BR

Comment: I was looking for a method in kotlin to do something like: ```list.chunkedBy { currentSum > 16 }``` if  currentSum greater than 16 then it would add a new chunk, what I had found it was just chunking by size

Comment: By a nice way I was thinking something like ```list.chunkedBy { acc += it;  if (acc > 16) {acc = it; return true} else {return false} }```. For sure something to not creating these chunks by myself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

After trying to get some clarification around the spec from OP, I'm just aligning the expected output with answer from @gidds below.

```
fun Iterable<Int>.chunkedBy(max: Int) = this.filter { it < max }
    .fold(mutableListOf(mutableListOf<Int>())) { accumulator, current ->
        accumulator.apply {
            if (last().sum() + current > max - 1) add(mutableListOf(current))
            else last().add(current)
        }
    }

class ExtensionTest : BehaviorSpec({

    given("some input") {
        val input = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, 16, 13, 17, 10)

        val expected = listOf(
            listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
            listOf(6, 7),
            listOf(8),
            listOf(9),
            listOf(10),
            listOf(14),
            listOf(15),
            listOf(13),
            listOf(10)
        )

        `when`("folding") {

            val result = input.chunkedBy(16)

            then("result should be as expected") {
                result shouldBe expected
            }
        }
    }
})
```

---

**Original answer**

After some testing, this problem has two main aspects.

- Create a new collection with consecutive numbers only
- Map consecutive numbers into list of lists

For the former part, a while-loop is appropriate because it is easy to exit when condition is no longer met. That is not straight forward with e.g. `filter`.

For the latter part, `fold` may be used to map (reduce) the list of consecutive numbers into a list of lists.

Please observe that in addition to `val result`, just a single explicit declaration is used: `var index`.

Code is written inside a Kotest.

```
import io.kotest.core.spec.style.BehaviorSpec
import io.kotest.matchers.shouldBe

class MyTest : BehaviorSpec({

    given("some input") {
        val input = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 13, 17, 10)

        val expected = listOf(
            listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
            listOf(6, 7),
            listOf(8),
            listOf(9),
            listOf(10)
        )

        `when`("folding") {

            val result = mutableListOf(input[0]).apply {
                /** build a list of consecutive numbers only */
                var index = 1
                while (index < input.size
                    && input[index] < 16
                    && last() == input[index] - 1
                ) add(input[index++])
            }.fold(mutableListOf(mutableListOf<Int>())) { accumulator, current ->
                accumulator.apply {
                    /** if sum of current "chunk" will be greater than 15 */
                    if (last().sum() + current > 15) add(mutableListOf(current))
                    /** add element to current "chunk" */
                    else last().add(current)
                }
            }

            then("result should be as expected") {
                result shouldBe expected
            }
        }
    }
})
```

May be stripped down to 8 lines and still pass checkstyle (just for comparison with other answers with different degree of readability)

```
val result = mutableListOf(input[0]).apply {
    var index = 1
    while (index < input.size && input[index] < 16 && last() == input[index] - 1) add(input[index++])
}.fold(mutableListOf(mutableListOf<Int>())) { accumulator, current ->
    accumulator.apply {
        if (last().sum() + current > 15) add(mutableListOf(current)) else last().add(current)
    }
}
```

`apply`: Extension method that uses `this` internally and returns the receiver, as opposed to `run` that returns the result of the lambda.

`also` and `let` are the counterparts to `apply` and `run` that are using `it` internally.

**Also tested**

Code should handle cases where a new sequence of consecutive numbers appear in the input, e.g.:

```
val input = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 6, 7)
val expected = listOf(listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general-purpose `chunkedBy()` function I wrote to achieve this:

```
/**
 * Splits a collection into sublists not exceeding the given size.
 * This is a generalisation of [List.chunked]; but where that 
 * limits the _number_ of items in each sublist, this limits 
 * their total size, according to a given sizing function.
 *
 * @param maxSize None of the returned lists will have a total size 
 *                greater than this (unless a single item does).
 * @param includeAll Whether to include all items, even those
 *                   that are individually over the limit.
 * @param size Function giving the size of an item.
 */
fun <T> Iterable<T>.chunkedBy(maxSize: Int, includeAll: Boolean = true, size: (T) -> Int): List<List<T>> {
    val result = mutableListOf<List<T>>()
    var sublist = mutableListOf<T>()
    var sublistSize = 0L
    for (item in this) {
        val itemSize = size(item)
        if (itemSize > maxSize && !includeAll)
            continue
        if (sublistSize + itemSize > maxSize && sublist.isNotEmpty()) {
            result += sublist
            sublist = mutableListOf()
            sublistSize = 0
        }
        sublist.add(item)
        sublistSize += itemSize
    }
    if (sublist.isNotEmpty())
        result += sublist

    return result
}
```

```
// Example:
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 13, 17, 10)
println(list.chunkedBy(15, false){ it })
// prints: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7], [8], [9], [10], [15], [13], [10]]
```

(`includeAll` defaults to true, as that suited all the cases in which I've needed it.  But setting it to false does what you want here.)

(I've used this in a few places, and it's come up on this site before — it seems useful enough that I'm surprised it's not in the standard library.)

Comment: @Roar S. I think OP did not enumarate all expected chunks :( This answer is fine.

Comment: if ```chunkedBy``` just would be in the Kotlin's library, I was just looking for Kotlin 2-3 lines solution

Comment: @ocos After new info in the question, I tend to think you're correct about incomplete spec. I removed my comment. BR